# Azure Cosmos DB indexing for gremlin queries

Tags: database, azure, indexing, gremlin, cosmos

I have gone through many documents where indices are created but the APIs used are SQL API for Azure cosmos but no example for Gremlin API. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: Hi ,If my answer is helpful for you, you can  accept it vote it up as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure Cosmos DB is a schema-agnostic database that allows you to iterate on your application without having to deal with schema or index management. **By default, Azure Cosmos DB automatically indexes every property for all items in your container without having to define any schema or configure secondary indexes**.

For more details, we can see [Indexing policies in Azure Cosmos DB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/index-policy).

Azure Cosmos DB support [Gremlin API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/graph-introduction). You can use the indices for your Gremlin queries.

Reference: [Querying with indexes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/index-overview#querying-with-indexes)

Hope this helps.